# UIImagePickerController Crashing when Trying to Load Large Images

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm experiencing an issue where UIImagePickerController is crashing when trying to load large images.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //These are the methods of selecting from camera roll directly
    @IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum

        present(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is the image that I am using that crashes the UIImagePicker:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykfflbo3es814wb/Circles.PNG?dl=0

To duplicate the issue, once the ImagePicker opens, pick the large image and zoom in a little. When you click "use", you should see the UIImagePicker crashing in the XCode console.

Note: if you don't pinch to zoom a little, the UIImagePicker doesn't seem to crash.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Here is what XCode reports in the console when the error occurs:

```
2020-01-31 13:21:45.015647-0600 Large Image Test[9899:5765569] [lifecycle  ] [u 2FCDF773-5F10-419C-84D2-1D8832227BE8:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.
2020-01-31 13:21:45.016058-0600 Large Image Test[9899:5746381] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
2020-01-31 13:21:45.016305-0600 Large Image Test[9899:5746381] [Generic] -[PUPhotoPickerHostViewController viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:] Error Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Comment: what does crash say ? please share crash logs

Comment: can you share crash logs

Comment: did you set permissions in info.plist?

Comment: Yes, all permissions are set correctly in info.plist. Please note that this issue does not occur when picking a standard sized image. It is only when a large image is picked that it crashes.

Comment: Please see crash reports above in edited post.

Comment: It's just a message in the console. Ignore it.

Comment: I would ignore it, but when the above errors are displayed, the UIImagePicker does not return any image data.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem, but I think it's no image file size, but image dimension (pixel  size). I don't know how to fix this =/

Comment: Having same issue here. I tried to downscale the size to 50% and it works again. It maybe an iOS limitation or bug.

Comment: Having similar issue here. I am having the same console error with my iPhone XR. I set the sourceType to .photoLibrary and the imagePicker suddenly exits each time I try to enter All Photos album, which contains more than 5600 photos. It also exits when I try to enter Recents album with same amout of photos. It doesn't exit when I enter other albums with fewer photos.